# Geometry Nodes are not rendering the final image for any frame

Tags: rendering, geometry-nodes

I did Geometry Nodes animation of Fireworks and I can see the animation in the Viewport in Cycles and EEVEE, but when I try to render it output I get a blank content.

The file can run on Blender 3/4.

So my questions are:

1. The Geometry Nodes in the viewport are computed unrelated to the current Frame. meaning, if I play the viewport it will get to the end of the timeline and jump to frame 1 again, but the animation will continue like the timeline is endless.
   I want it to work for each frame in the correct frame data, like baking it or being consistent with any frame. so when I jump to frame 130 it will look like that specific frame.
   how to do it?
2. when I try to render any frame I still get an empty frame in the output rendering. I think it is related to #1 above, but I don't know if it is correct. I think it is on "frame 1" for any rendering.

See the attached blender file.
[image]

Please assist.

**Update (31/12/2023):**
Look like the issue is a recursive Geometry Nodes in the Buffer object that is related to Sim Geometry Nodes and the Sim related to Buffer object Geometry Nodes.

So, this causes an `undefined` when it tries to render the scene.

I need help in making the Blend file work without the recursion in the Geometry Nodes objects.

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

After checking with the Blender Dev team in the [following ticket](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/116676), the Buffer Hack is not something that can work on rendering, and it is working by luck.

So, it is nice for the viewport but not for rendering.